# Separating equation solutions using commas

Tags: math-mode

Let's say I want to write the solutions of an equation. I do it like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P(x)&=x(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)\\
x&= -1,0,1,2 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

However, the `-1,0,1,2` seems to be a bit squished.

Is this the proper way to write it out? Should they be separated by something more than just a comma? Maybe a `\,`, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would typeset it as `-1,\,0,\,1,\,2`, as you suggest. If this still looks too close, use `\:` or `\;` instead of `\,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to start by inserting a word-space (backslash followed by space) after each comma in question. The numbers read (syntactically) like separate words -- hence the word space suggestion

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P(x)&=x(x-2)(x-1)(x+1)\\
x^* &= -1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 2 \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SkeletonBow It doesn't take much to drive you crazy, as it seems. ;-)